# Avoid product backorders for "customer" user role in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, user-roles

I have two types of roles, normal customer and wholesale customers. The wholesale customers should be able to place backorders and the normal customers are not allow to place backorders. I am not a php developer and my code is not working yet, please help me out to make it work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed( $backorder_allowed, $product_id, $product ){
    $targeted_user_role = 'zakelijke_klant';
    $user_data = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
    if ( in_array( $targeted_user_role, $user_data->roles ) ) {
         $backorder_allowed = true;
    }
    return $backorder_allowed;
}
```

Comment: Code looks good from naked eye. Can you put some sort of debug to see if this filter function receives control. A very simply way could be to use `wp_mail` with `echo $product_id` in it. It will tell us that filter does not have any syntax error and is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following targeting the normal "customer" user role instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 'woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_product_backorders_allowed( $backorder_allowed, $product_id, $product ){
    if ( current_user_can('customer') ) {
        $backorder_allowed = false;
    } else {
        $backorder_allowed = true;
    }

    return $backorder_allowed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.